# How do you restore the open new note shortcut after the latest Evernote update (Version 5.0.7)?

Tags: evernote, mac

In the latest Evernote update it seems they changed the functionality of the shortcut cmd-ctrl-n.  Previously it would open a new note in a window by itself.  You could then use additional shortcuts on that note to move the note to a different notebook, add tags, etc.  Now, instead a "mini" note with reduced functionality opens right below the elephant icon on the top menu bar.  How can I restore the previous functionality so I can use all my shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality to open an Evernote in a new window still exists - it has just been masked by this new "quick note" functionality.

The previous capability to create a note in a new window is currently mapped to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> instead.

You can restore the previous method and stop using (or change) the "quick note" interface by clicking Evernote → Preferences → Shortcuts.  There you can change the keyboard mapping from "Quick Note" to something else and map item named "New Note Window" back to the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd>  (or whatever you prefer).